# What does a float variable followed by parenthesis mean?

Tags: c, floating-point, precision, sensors

I was recently browsing for some examples to revisit C and came across a code where OP declared a variable as:

```
float Get_TMP007_Data();
```

What do the parenthesis in the variable name imply since this is not an array declaration?

Comment: It looks to be a function prototype for a function that returns a float.

Comment: It's a function declaration (but not a prototype because there is no information about what parameters it takes, except that it does not take a variable length argument list; `printf()` takes a variable argument list, indicated by `, ...` at the end of the prototype).  The declaration specifies that the function returns a `float`.  It would be a prototype if it said `float Get_TMP007_Data(void);` (it takes no argumentes) or listed some types, optionally with parameter names: `float Get_TMP007_Data(int val1, double temp2);` or something similar.

Comment: A couple of C++-related notes: in C++ this is a prototype (even without the `void`) and in C++ a construct like this (in particular when a class type is used instead of a built-in like `float`) is often referred to as the "most vexing parse" because it looks like a variable that is being default initialized, but in fact it's a declaration of a function that takes no arguments and returns a value of the specified type.

Comment: I understand it now. Thanks to everyone for the prompt replies :)

Answer (score 0):

That's not a variable, that's a function prototype. A common requirement (depending on the structure of your code/files) in gcc is to have them.

They're basically just the function header of a function you have written something else, something used for the pre-processor to determine what functions are being used/written. What you have there is a function called    Get_TMP007_Data() that returns a float

Answer (score 0):

`float Get_TMP007_Data();` is a function *declaration*.

It is a [declare Get_TMP007_Data as function returning float](https://cdecl.org/?q=float+Get_TMP007_Data%28%29%3B).

---

As a *declaration* of a function, there is no information as to what paremters should be passed.  It could be used as

```
float f1 = Get_TMP007_Data();
float f2 = Get_TMP007_Data(42);
```

A better function declaration would list the parameters to be passed - perhaps even none as in:

```
float Get_TMP007_Data(void);
```